# Unable to execute chromeDriver -v in Linux debian, is this an installation issue? Chromedriver error in digital ocean app platform

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, debian, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

Thanks in advance

I install chromedriver in debian /usr/bin. However, when I use chromeDriver -v, it always say command not found. Does this mean installation issue?

I installed Chrome with version 119.0.6045.195
from google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

I download  chromedriver from

- https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/119.0.6045.105/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
- 

and installed with these command below in chromedriver-linux64 folder

```
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver 
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

I am sure /user/bin/ has the chromedriver. But I don't know why I am unable to check version of chromedriver in debian.
Besides, I guess becasue of issue above, I got error after depolyed app in digitalocean APPs platform:

```
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]   File "/workspace/app.py", line 89, in <module>
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]     driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]     super().__init__(
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]     self.service.start()
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]     self.assert_process_still_running()
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59]     raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59] selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /workspace/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/119.0.6045.105/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59] 
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59] [2023-11-29 03:22:59 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59] [2023-11-29 03:22:59 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:14) exited with code 3
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59] [2023-11-29 03:22:59 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
[flight] [2023-11-29 03:22:59] [2023-11-29 03:22:59 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Reason: Worker faile
```

Comment: `win64` means version for `Windows` but you use `Linux`. You should visit official page https://www.google.com/chrome/ and download correct version for your system. Version for `debian` should have extension `.deb`, not `.zip`

Comment: for newest version you can visit https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ and download version for `linux64`, not `win64`  - `chrome-linux64.zip` and `chromedriver-linux64.zip`

Comment: @furas, sorry, it's typo, I copied wrong link, actually I did use   https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/119.0.6045.105/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip and google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: you may try to run `chromedriver` directly in console/terminal -  it may show more information.

Comment: @furas, if I just type chromedriver, says "no command found"

Comment: so try `/full/path/to/chromedriver` and if it works (without errors) then you can use `/full/path/to/chromedriver` in `Chrome(service=Service(executable_path="..."))`